# Clicking a Google Play link within a post's body attempts to render the page in place of the post

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

I'm not sure if the title explains this very well, but here's the scenario:

- Find a post with a Google Play link in the body (I was looking at [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14981/is-there-a-reliable-way-to-detect-the-app-responsible-for-an-airpush-ad) on Android Enthusiasts, second link; a relevant example on SO can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377472/navigation-drawer-google-vs-youtube), the last 3 links).
- Click on the link in the post body

What happens is that the app tries to render the linked page *in place of* the question body. Links to other sites seem okay, such as the first one in the above post; I can thus far only create this issue with links to Google Play apps. This doesn't seem to be a byproduct of the redirection from `market.android.com` to `play.google.com`, because clicking one of the links in [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/50260/981) creates the same behavior.

Visually, you go from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

Comment: Confirmed, we'll look into this. Thanks for the report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issues (and various similar ones with links in questions and answers) is fixed in version 0.1.3, which has just been uploaded to the Play Store.